# python pandas np.where value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause

I am trying to apply different value to a df from another column using:

```
df['url']= 
     np.where(df['client'] == 'xyz',
     "/s?k={query}&s=relevanceblender&page=%s".format(query=df['keyword']), 
     "other")
```

however query is replaced by all values of df['keyword'], not only the row in question. thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of `df`

Comment: didn't understand your question

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). It's good practice to provide a toy dataset as example when asking a question. Also see my answer, I provided one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'client': ['abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'xyz'],
                   'keyword': ['kw1', 'kw2', 'kw3', 'kw4']
                  })
```

You could use:

```
df['url'] = np.where(df['client'] == 'xyz',
                     df['keyword'].apply("/s?k={}&s=relevanceblender&page=%s".format),
                     'other')
```

*Notice how `{query}` was changed to `{}`.*

Or, if you cannot change the formatting string:

```
df['url'] = np.where(df['client'] == 'xyz',
                     df['keyword'].apply(lambda x: "/s?k={query}&s=relevanceblender&page=%s".format(query=x)),
                     'other')
```

Output:

```
  client keyword                                  url
0    abc     kw1                                other
1    abc     kw2                                other
2    xyz     kw3  /s?k=kw3&s=relevanceblender&page=%s
3    xyz     kw4  /s?k=kw4&s=relevanceblender&page=%s
```

Comment: IMO `lambda *args, **kwargs: '...'.format(*args, **kwargs)` would be better, no?

Comment: But actually I can't imagine how to make it work in case of several replacement parameters. Any idea?

Comment: @Vitalizzare you could do: `df.rename(columns={'keyword': 'query'}).apply(lambda x: "/s?k={query}&s={client}".format(**dict(x.items())), axis=1)`, not pretty but it works ;)

Comment: Or, probably better, using a dictionary comprehension: `pd.Series({k: "/s?k={query}&s={client}".format(**d) for k, d in df.rename(columns={'keyword': 'query'}).to_dict('index').items()})` (or list comprehension if you have duplicated indices).

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to do this is by vectorizing `"...".format`, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,2,3,4],
    'B': [*'abcd']
})

query_format = np.vectorize('Item {query!r} for {data!r}'.format)

df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] > 2, query_format(query=df['B'], data=df['A']), 'other')

print(df)
```

with this result:

```
   A  B               C
0  1  a           other
1  2  b           other
2  3  c  Item 'c' for 3
3  4  d  Item 'd' for 4
```

See [numpy.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) for more details.

Comment: Nice idea, however one should keep in mind that `vectorize` is only a convenience, it won't make things faster as string operations cannot really be vectorized ;)